# Failed to do Firestore export with service account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I used the following command to export Firestore db of my project, it works for a user account but failed for service account.

`gcloud alpha firestore export gs://<project_id>/backup/<date> --async`

I've added `storage.admin` and `datastore.importExportAdmin` to both accounts and indeed both account have exactly the same role, so is there anything special I need to do for service account?

I saw this note from the doc as well but I think it should not be related as it works for my project, but only not for a service account? Please help.

> NOTES
>
> This command is currently in ALPHA and may change without notice. If this command fails with API permission errors despite specifying the right project, you will have to apply for early access and have your projects registered on the API whitelist to use it. To do so, contact Support at https://cloud.google.com/support/.

Comment: Thanks for helping to edit @Frank, I saw people posted in Google Group that they can successfully export using service account, any hint on how I can debug on this?

Answer (score 0):

End up I've created another service account with the same IAM permission, and it works.. So maybe just something weird..